# How do I split 16-bit data into 2 8-bit data in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

How do I split 16-bit data into 2 8-bit data?

```
 signal part : std_logic_vector (16 downto 0);
 signal part_1    : std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
 signal part_2   : std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

The `part` is actually 17 bit, since `16 downto 0` is a 17 bit range, and the `part_*` are likewise 9 bit.

If the ranges are `15 downto 0` and `7 downto 0`, then you can do the split with:

```
part_1 <= part( 7 downto 0);
part_2 <= part(15 downto 8);
```

Btw, quote by Martin Fowler / Phil Karlton:

> There are two hard things in computer science: 
>   cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 1):

Why are your signals 17 bits and 9 bits long?  I think they should be 16 and 8...

```
signal part   : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
signal part_1 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal part_2 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

begin -- architecture begin  

part_1 <= part(15 downto 8);
part_2 <= part(7 downto 0);
```

Pretty simple stuff... I'm surprised you didn't run across this in looking at a VHDL example.

Answer (score 0):

There's also aggregate target assignment:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    type fie is array (natural range 0 to 1) of std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal part:   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    signal part_1: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal part_2: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
     (part_1, part_2) <= fie'(part(15 downto 8), part(7 downto 0));
end architecture;
```

Which is admittedly more useful for extracting elements of records in one fell swoop.  What's slick here is that there's no place there's any named signal of type `fie`.

The reason for the aggregate on the right hand side is because the element size has to match on both sides of the assignment operator, both aggregates are treated as if they are type `fie`.

Doing this with records allows you to extract elements of varying sizes. Extracting fields from CPU machine instruction formats comes to mind. It allows you to use simple names without requiring aliases for element selected names.  (There would be no named record).

When the element size is the same on both sides you can simply use a target aggregate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fie is
end entity;

architecture fum of fie is
    signal part:   std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    signal part_1: std_logic;
    signal part_2: std_logic;
    signal part_3: std_logic;
begin
     (part_1, part_2, part_3) <= part;
end architecture;
```

These aggregates all use positional association. You can also use named association. Record aggregates require an `others` choice represent at least one element and all the elements have to have the same type (e.g. `std_logic_vector`).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: you can also use aliases which makes the signal assignment obsolete:

```vhdl
    signal part  : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    alias part_1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) is part(15 downto 8);
    alias part_2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) is part(7 downto 0);
```